# What is the best practice to improve performance?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm newly learning and creating simple app using flutter.

I created drawer inside Scaffold for some pages and I got confused if when I click the ListTiles, should it be routing the pages or just switch the body widget using setState().

I guess setState() must perform better but I'm not sure if this is a good practice for pages. If it does not have a big difference in performance, I would like to use routing the pages since it will be uniformed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personal opinion:

- Avoid separating widgets into functions, use StatelessWidget instead. Cause every render function will rebuild whatever parameter changes.
- Avoid using `setState` as much as possible, especially for large Widgets, instead use [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider), [get](https://pub.dev/packages/get) or simply use [ValueNotifier](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/ValueNotifier-class.html) if you dont want library. Cause `setState` will mark all things to be rerender include widgets that not need to be rerender.
- Do not render too many things at once, if possible only render the views that are / are about to be displayed. Example [using ListView.builder instead of ListView](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/lists/long-lists), ... etc
- With image, please resize to suit your needs, a 2000x2000 image loaded as a 24x24 icon is clearly not a good idea.
- using `const`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to redirect user to the next page as it won't require a `StatefulWidget` (you can use navigator to navigate user to another activity) which will be lighter to run, as if you use IndexedStack or dynamically assign the widget it'll require the `StatefulWidget`..